# ListPlot - set x axis to label in integer steps.

Tags: plotting

Calling `ListPlot[{0, 0.1, 0.2}, DataRange -> {0, 2}]` produces a plot with markers in $x = 0.5$, $x = 1$, $x = 1.5$, and $x=2.0$.

I want to have markers only in $x = 0$, $x=1$, and $x=2$ (the integers). How can I do this?

Comment: `Ticks -> {{0,1,2,3,4,5}, Automatic}` ?

Comment: or `Ticks -> {Range[0,2,1], Automatic}`

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
ListPlot[
 {0, .1, .2},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{0, 1, 2}, None}}
 ]
```

**Output**

[image]